# Error occurred on saving new excel file using exceljs writeBuffer

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, xlsx, exceljs

I am using `exceljs`  library in my angular/electron project and I am trying to save a new updated excel file but an error occurred.

[image]

my code:

```
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
const data = await fs.promises.readFile('item.xlsx');
const wb = await workbook.xlsx.load(data.buffer);
const worksheet = wb.getWorksheet('Order');
const buffer = await wb.xlsx.writeBuffer();
const blob = new Blob([buffer]);
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, `${Date.now()}.xlsx`);
```

any suggestions.

Comment: maybe check the return value of getWorksheet() to see if it returns null?

Comment: the error occurs after calling writeBuffer(). getWorksheet() return object not null.